# Android Error FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, fatal-error

This is my error im getting while starting a aysncronic task.

```
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.edocsyl.spesen/ch.edocsyl.spesen.SpesenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at ch.edocsyl.spesen.SpesenActivity.onCreate(SpesenActivity.java:87)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-18 12:21:40.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 11 more
```

my code:

```
public class SpesenActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
static ApiRestClient arc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spesen);

    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    //params.put("username", "james");

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SpesenActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    arc.get("uebersicht.json", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            text.setText(response);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Can you help me?

Comment: At least look through the stacktrace before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `arc` before using it:

```
arc = new ApiRestClient();
arc.get("uebersicht.json", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        text.setText(response);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok i did this but now its loading infinitely

Comment: And im getting this Warning..

Comment: 01-18 13:28:13.120: I/Choreographer(1848): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-18 13:28:13.129: W/Trace(1848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-18 13:28:13.129: W/Trace(1848): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized `arc`. First create the object of arc and then try it.

```
arc = new ApiRestClient();
```

add above line of code before using `arc`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : read the stacktrace

Step 2 : identify the Exception

Step 3 : identify the class, method, and line that caused the exception

Step 4 : find a fix

Step 5 : if you can't find a fix, ask a question mentionning the result of all 4 previous steps